# Output all the different variables from a SELECT query in a while-loop

Tags: php, mysql

I want to `SELECT` three random and unique rows from a MySQL database, and populate three HTML "card" elements with some unique data. I'm now able to `SELECT` data from three random rows in my database, and I have a PHP `for-loop` that creates three HTML cards.

The issue I now have is that the last values from the SELECT query overwrites the various variables (`$username`, `$fullName` and `$age`) so the same variable value is printed three times, instead of printing the three unique and different card values. Is there a better solution to loop trough the variables from the `SELECT` query and assign different values to the three cards?

I guess that my issue is that I `SELECT` and `fetch_assoc` the cards, but the last row values are used for the variables that I then `echo` out three times in the `for-loop`.

The PHP code:

```
<?php require_once '../../php/core/init.php';

$sql       = 'SELECT username, name, age FROM app ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3';
$result    = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $username   = $row['username'];
        $fullName   = $row['name'];
        $age        = $row['age'];
    }

} else {
    echo '<p>No posts to show...</p>';
}

$conn->close();

?>

<div class="card-wrapper --center-align">
 <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
   echo '
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__title">
           <h5>'.$fullName.', <span class="card__title--age">'.$age.'</span></h5>
           <p class="card__title--username">('.$username.')</p>
        </div>
    </div>';
 } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: in your `while` you are overwriting `$username` etc. So just take the `$row` and check in a loop for the values inside

Comment: Have you been able to solve?

Comment: Not really, I don't really understand what to do with a loop inside the `while-loop` I now understand that the variables get overwritten for every iteration of the `while-loop`, but I would somehow need to save the values with another loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to store each output from db into a main array and read from that one:

```
    <?php require_once '../../php/core/init.php';

    $sql       = 'SELECT username, name, age FROM app ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3';
    $result    = $conn->query($sql);


    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
         $username = [];
         $fullName = [];
         $age = [];
         $n = 0;

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $username[$n]   = $row['username'];
            $fullName[$n]   = $row['name'];
            $age[$n]        = $row['age'];
           $n++;
        }

    } else {
        echo '<p>No posts to show...</p>';
    }

    $conn->close();

    ?>

    <div class="card-wrapper --center-align">
     <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) { 
       echo '
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card__title">
               <h5>'.$fullName[$n].', <span class="card__title--age">'.$age[$n].'</span></h5>
               <p class="card__title--username">('.$username[$n].')</p>
            </div>
        </div>';
     } ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I can see it now, I just get a bunch of: Array to string conversion errors

Comment: Yeah, many thanks for the help. I still get the conversion error, I can mend it with print_r but is it wise to first echo out everything that's not the variables, and then use print_r to print the variable data, or would you do it in another way?

Comment: Can you post the errors? Which line? Did you get them also in your own code before?

Comment: Do not `echo` arrays. Use `print_r` or `var_dump` instead

Comment: Somehow I fixed it. Before I got the error of Array to string conversion when I for example used: `<h5>'.$fullName[$n].', <span class="card__title--age">'.$age[$i].'</span></h5>` But now when I used `<h5>'.$fullName[$i].', <span class="card__title--age">'.$age[$i].'</span></h5>` everything works just fine... so changing `[$n]` to `[$i]` fixed it. But how?